# Html file not loading from assets folder

Tags: android

I am trying to load from `asset` folder. I tried following and googling around. But, my file doesn't load up. It says  "Web page not available"

Here is my code:
`HelpActivity.java`

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1))
            .loadUrl("file///android_asset/help.html");
}

public void closeWindow(View v) {
    finish();
}

}
```

`help.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HelpActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </WebView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

`help.html`

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Should i include any permissions in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a `:` from your file protocol:

```
file:///android_asset/help.html
    ^
```

Comment: Same answer ... you were 2 seconds faster so to be fair-play, I deleted mine :)

Comment: correct answer...an another tutorial is useful available at http://lomza.people.totem-soft.com/?p=62

Answer (score 0):

```
((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)).loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView mWebVwRehat = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1;
        mWebVwRehat.setBackgroundColor(0); // to make webview transparent
        mWebVwRehat.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
```